# Marketing Cloud, LogUnsubEvent, AJAX, How to get Response?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ajax

I'm building a preference center page and am trying to make use of [LogUnsubEvent](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/unsubscribe_and_log_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call/).

Microsite Structure is:

- Unsubscribe Page
- Actions Page (contains LogUnsubEvent script)

When I use a form on Unsubscribe Page with an action to POST to Actions Page, everything works perfectly. However, I'd rather have the lead stay on the Unsubscribe Page. Using a jQuery AJAX call to the Actions Page results in...nothing. No opt out processed, no response.

What needs to be done to use an AJAX post instead of a form submission?

AJAX Call:

```
$("#optOutFormSubmit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#optOut").is(":checked")) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://cloud.email.customdecorators.com/Preferences/Actions",
        data: {
          email_address: "example@example.com",
          jobid: "123",
          listid: "123",
          batchid: "",
        }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        console.log("ajax posted");
        console.log(msg);
      });
    $("#optOutForm").hide();
    $(".sucessMessage").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(".helpText").removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Ampscript to write the message "success" to the page and changing the AJAX method to GET and then parsing the html for the "success" message (or fail).